# ng-click the button with no response

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The button is not work.

I click the button `ng-click="goSearchTitle()"` and it has no response.

Why it doesn't work?

```
    <body ng-app="myapp">

    <div ng-contoller="searchbyTitle">
        <h3>Search by Title</h3>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="searchTitle" placeholder="Enter a title" ng-model="searchTitle"/>
            <button type="button" id="goSearchTitle" ng-click="goSearchTitle()">Search</button>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script>
        angular.module("myapp", []).controller("searchbyTitle", function($scope, $http) {
            $scope.goSearchTitle = function(){
                alert($scope.searchTitle);
            }
        });
    </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: As a developer, you must always keep your _Developer tools_ open while development..

Comment: Change the app name to myapp

Comment: you also have typo in `ng-controller`

Answer (score 0):

Your app name is wrong.

```
<body ng-app="myapp">
```

Otherwise, angular will give an injector module error. You should always open console and see the errors to understand better

Answer (score 0):

You have typo @ `ng-contoller`, it is **`ng-controller`**

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myapp", []);
myApp.controller("searchbyTitle", function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.goSearchTitle = function() {
    alert($scope.searchTitle);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="searchbyTitle">
    <h3>Search by Title</h3>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="searchTitle" placeholder="Enter a title" ng-model="searchTitle" />
      <button type="button" id="goSearchTitle" ng-click="goSearchTitle()">Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```